# Не отображается список объектов на JSP

Tags: spring, java-ee, jsp, spring-mvc

Я хочу отобразить список студентов из базы данных на JSP. Но у меня ничего не отображается (хотя в самой базе есть записи).

Имею POJO Student.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Students")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "classNumber")
    private String classNumber;

    // Setters

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setClassNumber(String classNumber) {
        this.classNumber = classNumber;
    }


    // Getters

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getClassNumber() {
        return classNumber;
    }
}
```

Имею DAO (опущу все методы, кроме ключевых):

```
@Repository
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(student);
    }
    ...
    // Тут неправильно реализовано?
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Student> listStudents() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Student> studentsList = session.createQuery("from Student").list();

        for(Student student: studentsList){
            System.out.println("Student list: " + student);
        }

        return studentsList;
    }
}
```

Мой web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Java School Library</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>    

</web-app>
```

Конфиг диспатчер-сервлета (dispatcherConfig.xml):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.slandshow" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Database Information -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javahelps"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="12345"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.slandshow.model.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!--BookDao and BookService beans-->
    <bean id="studentDao" class="com.slandshow.dao.StudentDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="studentService" class="com.slandshow.service.StudentServiceImpl">
        <property name="studentDAO" ref="studentDao"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.slandshow"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Контроллер (опущу всё лишнее):

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    private final String STUDENT_LISTING_VIEW = "students";
    private final String STUDENT_REGISTRATION = "registration";

    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "studentService")
    public void setBookService(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "students"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listBooks(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("students", this.studentService.listStudents());

        return STUDENT_LISTING_VIEW;
    }
    ...

}
```

И JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>List of Students</title>

    <style>
        tr:first-child{
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #C6C9C4;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>
<h2>List of Students</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>NAME</td><td>CLASS</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
        <tr>
            <td>${student.name}</td>
            <td>${student.classNumber}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<br/>
<a href="<c:url value='/add' />">Add New Student</a>
</body>
</html>
```

И так-же, я получаю следующий стек-трейс:

```
26-Aug-2018 01:35:44.651 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setStudentService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'studentDao' while setting bean property 'studentDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources;)V
26-Aug-2018 01:35:44.660 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setStudentService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'studentDao' while setting bean property 'studentDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:554)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'studentDao' while setting bean property 'studentDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1611)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1611)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources;)V
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
    ... 97 more
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не создается бин DAO из-за того что возникает эксепшн: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources;)V`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бин не инжектится. Для этого используй @Autowired над полем. Или Использовать @PersistenceContext если будешь использовать Jpa.